# изменить атрибут у тэга

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть тэг `<img src="/image123h100w100.jpg">`. Как с помощью jquery заменить `h100w100` на `h200w200` после загрузки страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="/image123h100w100.jpg" class="needs-higher-resolution" />

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".needs-higher-resolution").attr("src", function(index, src){
    $(this).removeClass("needs-higher-resolution"); // optional
    return src.replace("h100w100", "h200w200");
  });

});
```

От Grundy - [Ссылка на документацию к методу](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

Comment: [Ссылка на документацию к методу](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: @Grundy - благодарю

Comment: Стоит добавить в ответ :-)

Comment: спасибо! в моем случае помогло $(windows).load(function(){ваш код});